# Constructing a single page blog with pagination

Tags: channel-entries, channel, pagination, navigation

Here's the scenario

I have a bunch of blogs to be displayed. 9 blogs with short description in a grid, and then click on the caption to read more of the blog

the blog grid url is www.mysite.com/person1/blog

on clicking the channel entry it takes me to the more detailed view. The url looks like this
www.mysite.com/person1/blog/blog-with-url

the url title of the channel entry is blog-with-url
I have accomplish this. What I am not able to achieve is, that I pagination to navigate to the next and the previous blog post. How should I do that?

Comment: Are the blogs in the same or separate channels? Can you post an example of your entries tag pair?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With - http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/entry_linking.html

```
{exp:channel:next_entry}
<p>Next entry: <a href="{path='site/comments'}">{title}</a></p>
{/exp:channel:next_entry}

{exp:channel:prev_entry}
<p>Previous entry: <a href="{path='site/comments'}">{title}</a></p>
{/exp:channel:prev_entry}
```